# Extraer valor del nodo XML

Tags: c#, xml

Buen dia jovenes algo de uds me puede ayudar... necesito acceder a este nodo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<dte:GTDocumento xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
<dte:SAT ClaseDocumento="dte">
<dte:DTE ID="DatosCertificados">
```

A : dte:SAT y acceder a ClaseDocumento='dte'y quisiera actualizar su valor...intente de esta manera en c#

```
XmlNode tgtnode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//dte:SAT/@ClaseDocumento");
tgtnode.InnerText = "EditMVC";
```

Pero obtengo este error :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **System.XML.XPath.XPathExeption:** Es necesario el administrador de espacios de nombres o XsltContext. Esta consulta tiene un prefijo, una variable o una funcion definida por el usuario.

Comment: Pido disculpas... ahorita lo corrijo

Comment: Ya lo edite....

Comment: Debes agregar un ejemplo del XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=net-7.0#system-xml-xmlnode-selectsinglenode(system-string-system-xml-xmlnamespacemanager) con el ejemplo debería ayudar:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("dte", "pon URI associada con prefijo dte aquí");

XmlNode tgtnode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//dte:SAT/@ClaseDocumento", nsmgr);
```